# Refresh img src with new random

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var rnd = Math.round((Math.random() * (1153 - 1) + 1));
while(!IsValidImageUrl("/engine/achigen/i/"+rnd+".png"))
    rnd = Math.round((Math.random() * (1153 - 1) + 1));
$("#achieve a img").attr("src", "/engine/achigen/i/"+rnd+".png");
```

I want to replace specified image with other when page loading. I have images 1.png..1153.png, but I need check if image src is valid.

```
function IsValidImageUrl(url) {
$("#achieve a img", {
    src: url,
    error: return false,
    load: return true
});
}
```

How I can it do? My way is wrong

Comment: `i need to check if image src is valid`- so do it. what's your question? what's wrong? you need to be very clear in your question.

Comment: You can't do that. http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: For the random number, try: rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1153) + 1); instead

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create an recursive/callback-based function that would repeat itself until it finds valid URL. For callback it is convenient to go with promise pattern.

Consider this example that should do the trick:

```
function IsValidImageUrl(url, success, error) {
    return $.Deferred(function () {
        $("#achieve a img", {
            src: url,
            error: this.reject,
            load: this.resolve
        });
    }).promise();
}

function generateImage() {
    var rnd = Math.round((Math.random() * (1153 - 1) + 1));
    return IsValidImageUrl("/engine/achigen/i/" + rnd + ".png").then(function() {
        return "/engine/achigen/i/" + rnd + ".png";
    }, generateImage);
}

generateImage().then(function(url) {
    console.log('valid url', url);
});
```

In this example, `IsValidImageUrl` returns a Promise object that resolves or rejects if the url is valid/invalid. Helper `generageImage` is used to invoke `IsValidImageUrl` until valid image is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this creating every image in js and listen for the onload,onerror events. Bare in mind that creating 1153 images will most certainly make the browser spit at you.

```
function loadImage(i){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        // image exists, do something with it, eg.
        // $('.container').append(this); or
        // $("#achieve a img").attr("src", this.src);
    };
    img.onerror = function(){
        // image does not exist, do something about it, eg.
        // load another one 
        // var anotherRandomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1153));
        // loadImage(anotherRandomNumber);
    };
    img.src = "/engine/achigen/i/" + i + ".png";
}

var randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1153));
loadImage(randomNumber);
```